# Which directories does iOS apps have permission to write and read from?

Tags: ios, permissions, jailbreak

I know that the you have read permission to files in the `/var/mobile/Library/Preferences` directory, however you don't have read permission to some other directories located in `/var/mobile/Library/`.

Where can I find a list of the allowed paths to read and write from inside an app running as mobile user?

I don't care if it is allowed to access the directory, so it can be submitted to the app store, as it is for a jailbreak tweak I am making.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied from http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Seatbelt section "Working around the sandbox":

```
Anything in the container itself (of course).
~/* except the Media and Library subfolders, which only the following directories are readable:
~/Media/DCIM/*
~/Media/Photos/*
~/Library/AddressBook/*
~/Library/Keyboard/*
~/Library/Preferences/*
```

Where `~` refers to `/var/mobile`